# nextjs console.log doesn't work inside function return function

Tags: next.js

I'm playing around with nextjs
and I've trouble to debug a function like
this:

```
export const authInitialProps = isProtectedRoute => {
  console.log("mylog");// this works 
  return ({ req, res }) => {
    console.log("inner my log", req); // this doesn't work
  };
};
```

Using in a page

```
ProfilePage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const auth = authInitialProps(true);
  if (!typeof auth === "function") {
    const user = await getUserProfile();
    return { user };
  }
  return { user: null };
};
```

I never see "inner my log" both in chrome console
and in my console terminal.
What's the problem please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this It may work:

```
ProfilePage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const auth = await authInitialProps(true); // await added
  if (!typeof auth === "function") {
    const user = await getUserProfile();
    return { user };
  }
  return { user: null };
};
```

I think it should be async to not pass over it!